# Does this three-faced 3D object have a name?

Tags: calculus, geometry, terminology

I’ve been trying to make a three-sided die. One of my solutions was to imagine how a sphere is made. A sphere is made by integrating the infinite circle cross sections until you get a sphere. What if you take a triangle and do the same thing? You would end up with a three-faced object with faces curved vertically but flat horizontally… some sort of spherical triangular prism. I’ve been searching forever but I can’t find any mention of this object anywhere. However, correct me if I’m wrong, but I was able to calculate the volume of such an object where “s” is the side length and “l” is the length:

$$\int_{-l}^{l}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \left(\frac{(s\sqrt{l^2-x^2})}{l}\right)^2 d x=\frac{s^2l}{\sqrt{3}}$$

This is similar to what the object looks like except this one is not as spherical:

[image]

Any ideas on what this object's formal name is?

Comment: related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the solid you're talking about. Let me propose somethiing and you tell me if I'm close. ¶ A sphere can be thought of as a series of horizontal circular cross sections from $z = -1$ to $z = 1$, where the center of each cross section is at $(0, 0, z)$ and the radius is $r = \sqrt{1-z^2}$. Are you asking what we get if we replace each of those with an equilateral triangle whose center is at $(0, 0, z)$ and which is inscribed in the corresponding circular cross section?

Comment: Yes Brian that's perfectly said, thats exactly what I'm thinking. Much clearer explanation than what I gave

Comment: It's a [hosohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosohedron).